# About quasi-linear finite automata

Tags: automata, transducers, finite-model-theory

Let M a finite state transducer define as : $M=<X,Y,S,\delta,\lambda>$
What we mean by quasi-linear finite automata?

Comment: In which context did you see this terminology? Would you have a reference?

Comment: @J.-E.Pin which can use the invertible transducer in cryptography.